# Как запустить приложение python на ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, vmware, app

У меня есть код на Python, мне нужно разместить его на виртуальной машине. На виртуалку я установил ubuntu, выглядит все так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как запустить код python на этой виртуалке, и как перенести на виртуалку код, если это нужно. Перенести файл не получится обычным перетаскиванием, так как все из чего состоит виртуалка - это командная строка ubuntu.

Comment: Можно подключиться к виртуалке по ssh (или просто sh)  (например, с помощью putty), передать файл через командную строку.

Comment: Общая папка host/guest будет работать даже в командной строке.

Comment: И запуск скрипта в консоли убунты ничем не отличается от запуска в консоли винды.

Comment: Перенос файлов - `sftp+FileZilla`. Собственно если у тебя там есть `ssh`, то 99,9% у тебя уже есть `sftp`.

Answer (score 1):

Запустить - **python3 main.py** - в той директории где находится твой код.
Что бы перейти в директорию в ubuntu - **cd имя_директории**
По поводу того как перенести код. Я бы это сделал через GitHub

Comment: `Я бы это сделал через GitHub` — ну, это же элементарно. настоящие пацаны делают **это** через vkontakte. или хотя бы через gmail. в крайнем случае — через vimeo.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, настоящие пацаны заливают на рапидшару.